# Replace a word in string

Tags: c, replace, substring, undefined-behavior, c-strings

How do i make below program work properly, The main problem i have seen so far is `str1` is not defined properly which may be the real cause for the program not working properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char string[]="We will rock you";
    char s1[10],s2[10];
    printf("Enter string 1 ");
    gets(s1);
    printf("Enter string 2 ");
    gets(s2);
    int start,end,compare;
    for(int i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
     if(string[i]==s1[0])
     {
        start=i;
        break;
     }
    //printf("%d",start);
    end=start+strlen(s1);
    //printf("\n%d",end);
    char str1[30],check[10];

//Defining string 1
    for(int i=0;i<start;i++)
     str1[i]=string[i];
    //printf("\n%sd",str1);
    
//Defining check
    for(int i=start;i<end;i++)
     check[i-start]=string[i];
     
    //printf("\n%s\n",check,str1);
    compare=strcmp(check,s1);
    //printf("\n%d",compare);
    
    if(compare==0)
     strcat(str1,s1);
     printf("\n%s",str1);
     
    for(int i=end,j=strlen(str1);i<strlen(string);i++)
    {
        str1[j]=string[i];
    }
    strcpy(string,str1);
    
    printf("\n%s",string);
}
```

I know this is not the best way to do it, it has so many loopholes as it wont work for words appearing again and it may also change words like (*ask, task or asking*) if str1 is given ask.
But still help me , What am i doing wrong???

Comment: **Rule 1:** Never use `gets()`. **Rule 2:** Never forget rule 1.

Comment: The `if(string[i]==s1[0])` can index `s1` out of range, because it has to be shorter than `string`. Anyway, you set `start` for every match, so surely `start` will be the end of the match, not the beginning? Also, you need *two* nested loops to find a substring match: every letter of `string` and every letter of `s1`. The solution looks like a "random guess".

Comment: @Weather Vane
mate respectfully, i think you are quite mistaken: if i input s1 *rock*, start will be assigned 8 as it should be, and yea my solution could be a random guess :) . If you have any better suggestion pls share with me and also can you clear what do you mean in your answer, I don't quite get it. and as mentioned above during run main problem seems to be while defining str1. not on start and all.

Comment: Yes I misread the first loop. Other things I notice: you should place a nul terminator at the end of `str1` and `check` after you build them, with `str1[start] = '\0';` and `check[end-start] = '\0';`. Also you did not increment `j` in the last loop (which has something else wrong, not sure what).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong???

For starters the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead either use `scanf` or `fgets`.

If in this for loop

```
int start,end,compare;
for(int i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
 if(string[i]==s1[0])
 {
    start=i;
    break;
 }
```

the condition `string[i]==s1[0]` does not evaluate to true then the variable `start` will have an indeterminate value because it is not initialized and all the subsequent code after the for loop invokes undefined behavior because there is used the uninitialized variable `start`.

If the condition evaluates to true then the value of end

```
end=start+strlen(s1);
```

can be larger than the length of the original string `string`. That again can invoke undefined behavior in this for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<start;i++)
 str1[i]=string[i];
```

After this for loop

```
for(int i=start;i<end;i++)
 check[i-start]=string[i];
 
//printf("\n%s\n",check,str1);
compare=strcmp(check,s1);
```

the array `check` does not contain a string. So calling the function `strcmp` also invokes undefined behavior.

It seems that in this call there is at least a typo.

```
if(compare==0)
 strcat(str1,s1)
```

it seems you mean

```
strcat( str1, s2 );
              ^^^
```

If `s1` was not found in `string` then this loop

```
for(int i=end,j=strlen(str1);i<strlen(string);i++)
{
    str1[j]=string[i];
}
```

just does not make a sense.

Pay attention to that in general the length of s2 can be greater than the length of s1. In this case you may not change `s1` to `s2` within `string` declared like

```
char string[]="We will rock you";
```

because that results in accessing memory outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Function replacing string in the string.

```
char *strreplace(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace, char *buff)
{
    int length = strlen(haystack);
    int needlelength = strlen(needle);
    int replacelength = strlen(replace);
    char *ptr = buff;
    char *start, *source, *dest;

    if (buff == NULL)
    {
        ptr = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        source = ptr;
        dest = haystack;
    }
    else
    {
        source = haystack;
        dest = buff;
    }

    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (buff == NULL) strcpy(ptr, haystack);
        else
        {
           if (!length) 
            {
                *buff = 0;
            }
        }
        while (needlelength && *source)
        {
            size_t chunklen;
            char *result;

            start = source;
            if ((result = strstr(source, needle)) == NULL)
            {
                strcpy(dest, source);
                break;
            }
            chunklen = result - start;
            strncpy(dest, start, chunklen);
            dest += chunklen;
            strcpy(dest, replace);
            dest += replacelength;
            source = result;
            source += needlelength;
        }
        if (buff == NULL)
        {
            free(ptr);
            ptr = haystack;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = buff;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and Sorry for bad English.
I think this code can help you

```
char* replace ( char text[] , char mainchar, char replace_char )
{
    char    out [120];
    char*   out_pointer  = out  ;
    register char      index_2=0;
    for ( register char index_1 = 0 ; index_1 < strlen (text) ; ++index_1 )
    {
        if ( text[index_1] != mainchar )
        {
            out_pointer[index_2]=text[index_1];
            ++index_2 ;
        }
        else
        {
            out_pointer[index_2]=replace_char;
            ++index_2 ;
        }
    }
    return out_pointer;
}
```

To use this function in your source code, proceed as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char* replace ( char text[] , char mainchar, char replace_char )
    {
        char    out [120];
        char*   out_pointer  = out  ;
        register char      index_2=0;
        for ( register char index_1 = 0 ; index_1 < strlen (text) ; ++index_1 )
        {
            if ( text[index_1] != mainchar )
            {
                out_pointer[index_2]=text[index_1];
                ++index_2 ;
            }
            else
            {
                out_pointer[index_2]=replace_char;
                ++index_2 ;
            }
        }
        return out_pointer;
    }
    char Array[100];
    strcpy (Array, replace("Hello", 'H', 'e'));
    printf ("%s", Array);
}
```